# why this code return unexpected result? (conditional variable)

Tags: c, linux, mutex

I am studying mutex lock.

so, I written test code about mutex lock.

but this code has a problem.

I want to show :

```
downloading.....
complete....
start play!
```

but at runtime, the result is :

```
downloading.....
complete....
```

I wnat know
 1. why this code has error?
 2. how to fix this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int buffer = 0;

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* download(void *arg){
    printf("downloading.....\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    sleep(3);
    buffer = 10;
    printf("complete....\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

void* play(void *arg){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    printf("start play!\n");
    --buffer;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, play, NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, download, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);

    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I'm horribly rusty at pthreads, but mutex_lock just before cond_wait doesn't look right. Also, you need not protect anything with mutex but `buffer` - no other code that access to that variable should be inside the mutex lock/unlock block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `download()` function happens to run first, acquire the mutex and do all of its work (including calling `pthread-cond_signal()` before releasing the mutex.

The `play()` thread has no opportunity to call `pthread_cond_wait()` before the signal is sent because `download()` happened to acquire the mutex first.  So when `play()` gets an opportunity to wait, it has already missed the signal that would wake it up.

The fix is to use the condition variable in conjunction with a flag (possibly `buffer` - depending on what you want to actually do).  Several things need to be done with the flag:

- the flag must be checked before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`, and if the flag indicates the condition is already met the wait should *not* be done
- the "check flag/wait only if condition is not met yet" operations should be performed in a loop because `pthread_cond_wait()` can return spuriously (ie., without a signal having been made)
- the flag check *and* any updates to the flag (in whatever thread) must be done while holding the mutex

Something like (the following code is untested):

```
void* play(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (buffer < 1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
    }
    printf("start play!\n");
    --buffer;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}
```